# Send mails in background without cron

Tags: php, mysql, linux, email, background-process

I was wondering if there is a way to run a PHP loop in order to send a few hundred emails to subscribers in background. My goal is to format the newsletter, click send and then close the browser or change page. Of course, the actual process of sending the e-mail will be running in background and would not be interrupted by the browser closing.

I know this can be made with a cron job reading from a queue saved in MySQL or text file, but this way, even if there is no queue for a long period, the cron will always be running, looking for the queue...

I've seen this funcionality in a script called Pommo (https://github.com/soonick/poMMo) but can't seem to understand how it's done.

Does anyone have an idea for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to add a comment to your question, but them I didn't have enough space there to format and give the example.

Here is an idea I believe might work:

1 - Load all the emails you want to send to a database or file.

2 - From your web application click on the button to send emails. This will submit an Ajax request to the server. You can define the number of emails you want to send within a certain timeframe. Remember that most hosts have limits on number of emails you can send every hour.

3 - create a php script that will receive the Ajax request and send all the emails within the parameters you define.

4 - I believe you can kill your web browser because the PHP script will run through the whole list and will not return until it finishes sending all the emails.

The above might work, however I would never do it this way. I would use a cronjob as stated above. Your cronjob would only have to check if there are emails to send or not. This is not resource intensive.

If you decide to implement the ideas above, please make sure you let us know. I am curious if that would work.

Good luck!

Comment: I think this would work if the php script had something like ignore_user_abort(true) or else it would be killed on browser closing, right?

Comment: @fana - from the PHP manual - "You can decide whether or not you want a client disconnect to cause your script to be aborted." You can read the full thing here -> http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Comment: there are some pretty interesting pieces of code in the comments of that page. I'll have to try them.

Comment: @fana - good luck. Sounds like an interesting challenge. I would be extra careful with the php timeout setting. Also, I suggest you write some code to confirm the script sent all the emails. Somehow I don't feel very comfortable with having a php script running "unattended" in the server... :O)

Answer (score 0):

> I know this can be made with a cron job reading from a queue saved in
>   MySQL or text file, but this way, even if there is no queue for a long
>   period, the cron will always be running, looking for the queue...

That pretty much beats the purpose of Cron. You should create a job that runs, say, every 15 minutes and checks the queue for mails that need to be sent. If there are no mails, let the script die, it'll run again in 15 minutes.

If there are mails to be sent, update the rows to indicate that you're processing them before you start sending, so a run taking more than 15 minutes won't cause another script instance to send the same mails.

Comment: I guess you are right. I just didn't want to create the cron job on every install, since I'm thinking of adding this system to a custom CSM... I also wanted it to start the process right away and risk having to wait X minutes until it starts...

Answer (score 0):

You need a queue system. There is e.g. [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) for linux, which you would feed things with php.

Comment: This is really good but seems to me it needs to be run through the command line or some django interface. I need it to be triggered by web interface.

Comment: you need to trigger it in "php interface"